# Does JsonPath support the AND (&&) operator?

Tags: jsonpath

Does JsonPath support the AND (&&) operator?

**Consider the following JsonPath expression:**

```
$.values[?(@.level=='First' && @.type == 'Sales')].selectedValue
```

Is this the correct syntax for "And" conditions for elements within an array?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the most authorative spec it is not supported: https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

However, there is a draft for a new standard which seem to include and-operator and more: https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/jsonpath/documents/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#inline-predicates):

> You can use `&&` and `||` to combine multiple predicates `[?(@.price < 10 && @.category == 'fiction')]` , `[?(@.category == 'reference' || @.price > 10)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what code library you are using.

The [spec](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) does indicate:

> Expressions of the underlying scripting language (<expr>) can be used
>   as an alternative to explicit names or indices as in
>
> $.store.book[(@.length-1)].title

...so the question becomes what the underlying scripting language is. In the original JavaScript implementation, it follows JavaScript.